# How to underline text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, dom

i have text like this in my editbox, `cat;dog;pig;tail`. but i want to underline them with ';'  separated in jquery. the string should look like this format in editbox.

```
cat ; dog ; pig ; tail
___   ___   ___   ____
```

How to do this in jquery?

```
<tr id="NameDetails">
                        <td>
                            <label for="<%=Names.Animal%>" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Name of Animals:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <%=Html.TextBox(Names.Animal, String.Empty, new { @class = "AnimalControl FreeText" })%> 
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Editbox? is that a textarea? Show underline while typing?

Comment: This can be possible, but you should post some effort..

Comment: Hi, its editbox. need not be while typing i dont need. once the focus is moved outof editbox i want them to get underlined

Comment: Rajaprabhu, i m new to jquery. :(, as i dont have much idea about this. please help if u have any idea

Comment: Oh.. ok fine. Atleast show your DOM structure..

Comment: You could set up a positioned element underneath for the dashes, then on the blur event count characters and insert however many dashes is appropriate.  Either that, or dynamically build the line of dashes in the onblur event, so it erases and builds again every time based on the first line.

Comment: No i dont want dashes exactly, i need a line i.e _______, it should look like this, its enough

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, i have updated please have a look

Answer (score 2):

You could use a jQuery script to convert a textarea to a div and fill it with spans of the words. Underline the spans with borders. Converting it back to a textarea on click and force focus.

HTML

```
<textarea class="textarea-underlined">cat ; dog ; pig ; tail</textarea>
```

jQuery

```
// Dynamically provide onBlur support for all newly added textarea elements.

$('body').on('blur','.textarea-underlined',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Copy textarea contents to array and split by semi-colon

    var contents = $(this).val();
    words = contents.split(';');

    // Create div and fill with styled spans.

    $(this).replaceWith('<div class="pseudo-textarea"></div>');
    words.forEach(function(el,index,arr){
        $('.pseudo-textarea').append('<span class="underlined">'+el.trim().toString()+'</span>');
        if(words.length-1 != index ){
            $('.pseudo-textarea').append(";");   
        }
    });
});

// Reverse the whole thing onClick of the div.

$('body').on('click','.pseudo-textarea',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Build array.
    var contents = new Array();
    $.each( $(this).find('span'), function( index, value ){
        contents.push( $(value).html() );
    });

    // Replace div with textarea and fill with array contents separated by semi-colon.

    $(this).replaceWith('<textarea id="textarea-underlined" class="textarea-underlined">'+contents.join(' ; ')+'</textarea>');
    $('#textarea-underlined').focus();
});
```

CSS

```
.underlined {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed black; // Your choice: solid, dotted, dashed...
}

.underlined:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed red; // Whatever color you want for hover.
}

span {
    margin-right: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}

// Make the textarea and div look the same.
.pseudo-textarea, textarea {
    cursor: text;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
    padding: 5px;
    resize: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px; width: 300px;
}

.pseudo-textarea > span:first-child{
    margin-left: 1px;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X8934/5/

Comment: Hi its working, but unless i click outside i cant edit the underlined strings, i need that edit feature too. what to do for  that?

Comment: Instead of `border-bottom`, can't you use `text-decoration:underline;`?

Comment: @Bharadwaj You could do text-decoration, but the example showed a dashed line with spacing below. I guess I took that for literally how it should look. Style away!

Comment: @LLL I am not understanding. Unless you click outside of what? The way this works is you click on the underlined strings to edit them, then you click away to show them underlined again. Could you explain the condition of the feature?

Comment: Hi SacWebdeveloper, Thank you for your help. Actually i want a feature like when you compose any mail, if you type contact name, the names will get underlined correct. like that i need feature. Here i just want the typed names to be underlined by (";") separated. is it possible??. So in a simple editbox i can type any number of names i want but as an when i type if its separated by ";" it should get underlined. like this i was looking for